# how to remove INR ₹ symbol from string

Tags: python

i have tried this following code,

value = 'Product Quantity Price Discount Cost Yammer Enterprise 1 ₹ 6,540.00 0.00 % ₹ 6,540.00 Total Cost ₹ 6,540.00 +91 81 4411 2222'
result = value.replace("₹", "")
print result

getting this 
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file main.py on line 4, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

how can i sovle this

Comment: The error message is pretty helpful. Did you specify an encoding?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this error in 2.7.12 and 3.6.2.